# Prevent wrapping comma-separated numbers in MS-Word

Tags: ms-word

I have long list of numbers in the following format:

123456,78910;123456,78910;123456,78910;...

I want to keep each number "123456,78910" together and not being wrapped. The wrap should be done after the semi-colon. How I can achieve that?

Comment: You can place them in a QUOTE field code. The content of a field code doesn't break across lines...

Comment: Works great with the quote field. Thank you, Cindy!